# How can I create documentation like the Eclipse or Fedora documentation?

Tags: documentation

I need a CMS that creates documentation like [Eclipse docs](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp) or [Fedora docs](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/index.html). I need search options and good looking printing support.

[image]

I don't want to hard code elements like current documentation generators such as [Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html), [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) or [GTK-Doc](http://www.gtk.org/gtk-doc/). I need something like a CMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Atlassian Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/), it is incredibly cheap for small teams ($10).  This is [how it looks](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/ALLDOC/Atlassian+Documentation) when used as a documentation CMS.

It is a heavy-weight Java application, so I don't know if it is applicable in your case. But it is quite nice and widely used as a documentation CMS, Wiki, etc. It is very powerful.

Comment: Is there any open source option? :D

Comment: Well confluence is actually free for open source projects: http://www.atlassian.com/software/views/opensource-license-request.jsp  But it itself is not open-source.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use Confluence for documentation and "intranetty" type sites ;-)

However, one open-source option which has a lot of similarities to Confluence is [XWiki](http://xwiki.org). Have a look through their [screenshots](http://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/Screenshots) for other sites that use XWiki.